# Barrier Synchronization between 2 process using mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I need to implement barrier synchronization between 2 threads using mutex (only). Barrier synchronization is that 2 threads will wait for each other to meet at predefined step before proceeding.

I am able to do it using seamaphore but **how can I achieve this only using mutex**. I was given a hint that I need 2 mutex not 1 to do this.

Using Seamaphore:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;

sem_t s1;
sem_t s2;


void* fun1(void* i)
{
    cout << "fun1 stage 1" << endl;
    cout << "fun1 stage 2" << endl;
    cout << "fun1 stage 3" << endl;
    sem_post (&s1);
    sem_wait (&s2);
    cout << "fun1 stage 4" << endl;
}

void* fun2(void* i)
{
    cout << "fun2 stage 1" << endl;
    cout << "fun2 stage 2" << endl;
//    sleep(5);
    sem_post (&s2);
    sem_wait (&s1);
    cout << "fun2 stage 3" << endl;
}

main()
{
    sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);
    int value; 
    sem_getvalue(&s2, &value);
    cout << "s2 = " << value << endl;

    pthread_t iThreadId;

    cout << pthread_create(&iThreadId, NULL, &fun2, NULL) << endl;
//    cout << pthread_create(&iThreadId, NULL, &fun2, NULL) << endl;
    pthread_create(&iThreadId, NULL, &fun1, NULL);
    sleep(10);
}
```

Compile the above code as "g++ barrier.cc  -lpthread"

Comment: Why `fun1()` and `fun2()` not returning `void*` !

Answer (score 1):

How about **NO MUTEXES** and no locks?  Using **ATOMIC OPERATIONS** only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

static sigset_t _fSigSet;
static volatile int _cMax=20, _cWait = 0;
static pthread_t    _aThread[1000];

void * thread(void *idIn)
{
int nSig, iThread, cWait, id = (int)idIn;

    printf("Start %d\n", id, cWait, _cMax);
    // do some fake weork
    nanosleep(&(struct timespec){0, 500000000}, NULL);
    // barrier
    cWait = __sync_add_and_fetch(&_cWait, 1);
    printf("Middle %d, %d/%d Waiting\n", id, cWait, _cMax);
    if (cWait < _cMax)
    {        
        // if we are not the last thread, sleep on signal
        sigwait(&_fSigSet, &nSig); // sleepytime
    }
    else
    {
        // if we are the last thread, don't sleep and wake everyone else up
        for (iThread = 0; iThread < _cMax; ++iThread)
            if (iThread != id)
                pthread_kill(_aThread[iThread], SIGUSR1);
    }

    // watch em wake up    
    cWait = __sync_add_and_fetch(&_cWait, -1);
    printf("End %d, %d/%d Active\n", id, cWait, _cMax);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int i, err;

    sigemptyset(&_fSigSet);
    sigaddset(&_fSigSet, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&_fSigSet, SIGSEGV);

    printf("Start\n");
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    if ((err = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 16384)) != 0)
    {
        printf("pthread_attr_setstacksize failed: err: %d %s\n", err, strerror(err));
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < _cMax; i++)
    {
        if ((err = pthread_create(&_aThread[i], &attr, thread, (void*)i)) != 0)
        {
            printf("pthread_create failed on thread %d, error code: %d %s\n", i, err, strerror(err));
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < _cMax; ++i)
        pthread_join(_aThread[i], NULL);

    printf("\nDone.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, atomic operations like __sync_add_and_fetch are only about 2x as slow as the non atomic counterparts.  Also when we experimented with mutexes/conditions vs sigwait, the sigwait method you see above tested 40x faster at sleeping and waking threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you need two mutexes, with one mutex and a condition variable and an extra flag might be enough. The idea is that you enter the critical section by acquiring the mutex, then you check whether you are the first thread to come, if so, you wait on the condition. If you are the second thread coming then you wake up the waiting thread and both leave.

Comment: I actually don't want to wait in a loop. Is there any other way?

Comment: @akash-agrawai There is no need to wait in a loop if you use a condition variable as David suggested. You can use ``pthread_cond_wait``.

Comment: @David: this is the sensible solution (and scalable to more threads), but it is a bit cheating if only mutexes are allowed.

Comment: @john-dibling I'm not sure, it's possible, my Google-fu is failing me. I'd be interested to know.

Comment: @stefaanv: I second you. In that way, we will be using kinda semaphore.

Comment: @Akash: it is only cheating if you're only allowed to use mutexes.  If you can use condition variables, please do.  If the solution needs to work with more threads, just increase and check the counter and broadcast the cv when all threads have reached the barrier (or even better: use pthread_barrier or boost::barrier)

Comment: @john: Unless I'm mistaken, spinlocks only spin for a very short time before giving up and sleeping the thread.